# How to resolve GeoCoordinates to spoken language?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, geolocation, geospatial

Given the latitude/longitude coordinates of a place, how can I determine the language spoken there ?

Are there any free databases that can resolve GeoCoordinates to the most likely language ?
Or city or administrative regions of a country to a language ?

Or any web services ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a service like [this](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrycode) to reverse geocode the lat/lon.  That will give you a country information.  There might be something online to help you match country code to language.. if not it shouldn't be that difficult to create lookup table for it.

Comment: If 1 country would have 1 and exactly 1 language, then this would hold true, but it's not the case, so it's a little bit more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the service provided by [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)
If you have the coordinates, you can use [Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

Check the whole information about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)

After you got the name of the country, you can use the [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1021kkz0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of the framework to get what you need.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hope you don't end up in [Quebec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec) - Let's see now: Canada -> English?

Comment: @Bo Persson: Same thing goes for Switzerland, except that we have 4 languages, not just 2 - however, I didn't count the Eskimos, so two for Canada might be unfair ;)

Comment: Let's get a better example, let's get [India](http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0855611.html) {17 languages and over 1600 dialects}, but that's not the point... there's all in the [c# culture names](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/), I think using this service and the info in those links, would be very helpfull!

Comment: @Luis: Maybe it's not clear, but I don't need a list of all languages of the country with matching (lat/long), I need the one language spoken most-likely at the reverse-geocoded coordinates (long/lat) within a country.